# Why are Casimir operators required to be Hermitian?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

What is the physical significance of requiring Casimir operators (of e.g. Poincare group or the conformal group) to be Hermitian? What breaks down if we do not impose this condition?

EDIT:

To be perhaps a bit more specific, one of the Poincare Casimir operators is momentum squared, with eigenvalue negative mass squared

$$C_2=P^\mu P^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu}=-m^2$$

where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the mostly plus Minkowski metric. If $C_2$ is not Hermitian, then the eigenvalue $-m^2$ can take on not only real but also complex values. So another way to ask is -- what would break down, from group theory and representation theory perspective, if masses of irreducible representations in Minkowski space are allowed to be complex?

Comment: Sorry I fail to follow.  Casimirs are invariant and act a multiple of the unit operator inside an irreducible representation, and are *constructed* as Hermitian from the get-go, *v.g* $L^2=L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$.  The physics tells you $L^2$,  not $iL^2$, has a physical interpretation.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Right, in the Poincare case, or rotation, we have additional knowledge of what is physical, by knowing that eigenvalues of familiar operators which the casimir is constructed from are real. But I wonder if there is a group theoretic reason as well, like requiring Hermiticity to have a completeness and orthogonality notion for different characteristic numbers, or similar argument?

Comment: You can go to a basis where the Killing form is diagonal and the Casimir is automatically a combination of Hermitian operators, up to an overall factor.

Comment: Note that when acting on indecomposable reps there can be a non-diagonal action.